# ?a method to find lexicographical minimum in arraylist of arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

StackOverflow people!

say, i have such arraylist (output with toString())

```
[[4, 5], [2, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

it's an `ArrayList <ArrayList <Integer> >`

i need to choose the lexicographical minimum out of it - ie, in this case `[1,2]`

for example, in such arraylist:

```
[[5],[1]]
```

i need to choose `[1]`

as you have noticed, all inner arraylists are of the same size.

please, tell me, what's the good way to extract such a lexicographical minimum.

thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Collections.min()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29), and provide your own comparator class that implements a lexicographical comparison of two `ArrayList<Integer>` objects.

As you're probably aware, a lexicographical comparison simply involves iterating over both input lists until either you hit the end of one of them, or until their corresponding elements differ in value.